# How to validate decimal value in vee validate 3.0 version

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I want to validate latitude and logitude value and my code is

```
    <ValidationProvider :name=waypointLang.form.latitude rules="required|decimal">
        <div slot-scope="{ errors }">
            <input v-model="waypoint.latitude" readonly name="latitude" type="text" autofocus :placeholder="waypointLang.form.latitude" class="form-control" id="latitude"/>
                   <span class="required-field">{{ errors[0]}}</span>
        </div>
    </ValidationProvider>
```

I got error No such validator 'decimal' exists.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add a custom rule by adding this to your ./plugins/vee-validate.js file:

```js
extend("decimal", {
  validate: (value, { decimals = '*', separator = '.' } = {}) => {
    if (value === null || value === undefined || value === '') {
      return {
        valid: false
      };
    }
    if (Number(decimals) === 0) {
      return {
        valid: /^-?\d*$/.test(value),
      };
    }
    const regexPart = decimals === '*' ? '+' : `{1,${decimals}}`;
    const regex = new RegExp(`^[-+]?\\d*(\\${separator}\\d${regexPart})?([eE]{1}[-]?\\d+)?$`);

    return {
      valid: regex.test(value),
    };
  },
  message: 'The {_field_} field must contain only decimal values'
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. This is very helpful. It would be great if this validated the number of decimal points also.

Answer (score 0):

You can also solve this with BigNumber.js if you need to support larger numbers and exponentials:

```
Validator.extend('decimals', {
    validate(value, args) {
        const decimals = new BigNumber(value).decimalPlaces()

        if (args[0] === null || args[0] === undefined) {
            return decimals >= 0
        }

        return decimals <= args[0]
    }
})
```